# how array of object value update permanetely

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I am trying to update my active status according to the input

I am trying like this my code

```js
const doctorID = "DR001"
const startTime = "12:15"
const doctors = [{
    doctorID: 'DR001',
    FirstName: 'aman',
    LastName: 'kumar',
    Price: 640,
    Currency: 'rs',

    slotsTime: [{
        active: true,
        startTime: '12:00',
        endTime: '12:15'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '12:15',
        endTime: '12:30'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '16:00',
        endTime: '16:15'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '16:15',
        endTime: '16:30'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    doctorID: 'DR002',
    FirstName: 'aman',
    LastName: 'kumar',


    Price: 640,
    Currency: 'rs',

    slotsTime: [{
        active: true,
        startTime: '10:00',
        endTime: '10:15'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '10:15',
        endTime: '10:30'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '14:00',
        endTime: '14:15'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '14:15',
        endTime: '14:30'
      },
    ],
  },

];



// Find the doctor object with the matching doctorID
const doctor = doctors.find((doc) => doc.doctorID === doctorID);

// Update the slotsTime array based on the startTime input
doctor.slotsTime = doctor.slotsTime.map((slot) => {
  if (slot.startTime === startTime) {
    return {
      active: false,
      startTime: slot.startTime,
      endTime: slot.endTime
    };
  } else {
    return slot;
  }
});

// Log the updated doctor object
console.log(doctor);
```

I got this output

```
{
  doctorID: 'DR001',
  FirstName: 'aman',
  LastName: 'kumar',
  Price: 640,
  Currency: 'rs',
  slotsTime: [
    { active: true, startTime: '12:00', endTime: '12:15' },
    { active: false, startTime: '12:15', endTime: '12:30' },
    { active: true, startTime: '16:00', endTime: '16:15' },
    { active: true, startTime: '16:15', endTime: '16:30' }
  ]
}
```

Now I want if again my input this

```
const doctorID = "DR001"
const startTime = "12:00"
const doctors = [
  {
    doctorID: 'DR001',
    FirstName: 'aman',
    LastName: 'kumar',
     Price: 640,
    Currency: 'rs',

    slotsTime: [
      { active: true, startTime: '12:00', endTime: '12:15' },
      { active: true, startTime: '12:15', endTime: '12:30' },
      { active: true, startTime: '16:00', endTime: '16:15' },
      { active: true, startTime: '16:15', endTime: '16:30' },
    ],
  },
  {
    doctorID: 'DR002',
    FirstName: 'aman',
    LastName: 'kumar',
 

    Price: 640,
    Currency: 'rs',
 
    slotsTime: [
      { active: true, startTime: '10:00', endTime: '10:15' },
      { active: true, startTime: '10:15', endTime: '10:30' },
      { active: true, startTime: '14:00', endTime: '14:15' },
      { active: true, startTime: '14:15', endTime: '14:30' },
    ],
  },
 
];
```

Then I got output like this

```
{
  doctorID: 'DR001',
  FirstName: 'aman',
  LastName: 'kumar',
  Price: 640,
  Currency: 'rs',
  slotsTime: [
    { active: false, startTime: '12:00', endTime: '12:15' },
    { active: false, startTime: '12:15', endTime: '12:30' },
    { active: true, startTime: '16:00', endTime: '16:15' },
    { active: true, startTime: '16:15', endTime: '16:30' }
  ]
}
```

I want when active status update once he always false when next active status update false then got both status false previous and next.

Comment: Don't reinitialize the `doctors` array each time. You can save it in `localStorage` between runs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understood you question, but it seems you want to make your change on the `active` attribute in the original object before returning, so it will be there for the next interactions.

If that is the case, this is what you could do:

```
if (slot.startTime === startTime) {
    slot.active = false
    return slot;
} else {
    return slot;
```

Edit: Added a snippet for better understanding:

```js
const doctors = [{
    doctorID: 'DR001',
    FirstName: 'aman',
    LastName: 'kumar',
    Price: 640,
    Currency: 'rs',

    slotsTime: [{
        active: true,
        startTime: '12:00',
        endTime: '12:15'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '12:15',
        endTime: '12:30'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '16:00',
        endTime: '16:15'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '16:15',
        endTime: '16:30'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    doctorID: 'DR002',
    FirstName: 'aman',
    LastName: 'kumar',


    Price: 640,
    Currency: 'rs',

    slotsTime: [{
        active: true,
        startTime: '10:00',
        endTime: '10:15'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '10:15',
        endTime: '10:30'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '14:00',
        endTime: '14:15'
      },
      {
        active: true,
        startTime: '14:15',
        endTime: '14:30'
      },
    ],
  },

];

const doctorID = "DR001"

// First time updating the doctor
let startTime = "12:15"
let doctor = doctors.find((doc) => doc.doctorID === doctorID);
doctor.slotsTime = doctor.slotsTime.map((slot) => {
  if (slot.startTime === startTime) {
    slot.active = false;
    return slot;
  } else {
    return slot;
  }
});
console.log(doctor);

// Second time updating the doctor
startTime = "12:00"
doctor = doctors.find((doc) => doc.doctorID === doctorID);
doctor.slotsTime = doctor.slotsTime.map((slot) => {
  if (slot.startTime === startTime) {
    slot.active = false;
    return slot;
  } else {
    return slot;
  }
});
console.log(doctor);
```

Comment: if am again take different input const doctorID =''DR001", const startTime="16:00"  so my pervious result not change as like  if  i am pervious take startTime ='12:00' and after update it active false he always false here problem when i take different time pervious status true show but its false

Comment: hm...   __what?         .__